# Can I transfer security certificates for VPN to my PC? -or- Where do I find VPN passwords?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I'm trying to use Defender VPN for my PC.  It works on my iPhone.  I'm using some kind of security certificates.  But the Windows installation of VPN via the "connect to a workplace" wizard in the "Network and Sharing Center" asks for a username and password.

Comment: How did you get the certificates for your iPhone? What kind of certificates are those? Did you get some sort of configuration file with those certificates?

Comment: It seems to me that it in asking for vpn access. It is asking for the destination machines password to instance the vpn instance. Please provide the destination password and check

Comment: @slhck The certificates just came with the application.  I'm very inexperienced with VPN.  But when I installed the app and opened it, it browsed to api.vpndefender.com and then asked me to verify a couple of certificates (two of them).

Comment: @vembutech Well, the thing is, there's no password given on the iPhone version of the app.  I'm just typing the server info into my PC.  So, I'm not sure if there's some other way to connect to a vpn that doesn't require a pass or that takes certificates in lieu of a pass...

Comment: And are you allowed to use the VPN on Windows? Is it officially possible? Then just follow the support instructions for doing so. If not, and you just got certificates for iPhone, then you can't run it on your PC, because you probably won't get the certs off your iPhone.